# Does Andrew Ryan survive the events of BioShock?

Tags: bioshock-series

Throughout BioShock, if the player dies, they resurrect from a conveniently placed Vita-Chamber. I assumed the Vita-Chamber was simply a clever way to mask the player overcoming death, and as a story element, should be ignored.

However, rather then simply being a means to an end, the Vita-Chamber is a legitimate piece of technology being used in Rapture. We should assume that the Vita-Chamber is relevant to the story, and not just a "story teller element" to mask the players constant death.

> In BioShock 2, it is revealed that the main character comes back to life, after his Little Sister programs his D.N.A. into the Vita-Chamber system.

Throughout the game, you find notes on the Vita-Chamber system. One, in particular, gives you an important piece of information. The Vita-Chambers are only tuned to Andrew Ryan's D.N.A. and should ideally only resurrect Andrew Ryan.

> It is shortly thereafter revealed that you are Andrew Ryan's son, and that is why the Vita-Chambers can resurrect you. Furthermore, The player character of BioShock 2 is first resurrected many years after his death. So there is a reasonably loose time requirement. At least up to ten years.

Given what we learn from the two games, a conclusion can easily be made. If Andrew Ryan were to die within fair proximity to a Vita-Chamber, he would simply reconstruct at the Vita-Chamber, just as the player does in BioShock and BioShock 2.

> As soon as the player kills Andrew Ryan, he is able to resurrect from a nearby Vita-Chamber, and escape.

My question is, does he show up later, at all?

Can anyone confirm this a deliberate twist, and not just a simple a plot oversight?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You're thinking a bit too much into it. There's a Vita-Chamber in Ryan's office, however...

> It is disabled. Ryan turned it off. He chose, he did not obey.

I would give you a screenshot, but my Bioshock savefiles are long gone.

Ryan didn't need to run away. He didn't want to. Rapture was his life. and by that time...

> He had set in motion its destruction, by himself. He would rather die with his city than letting what was left of it to be in the hands of Atlas; who he probably suspected to be Fontaine, but we have no confirmation about it. Moreover he **wanted** his city to die with him. Because *he was rapture, and rapture was him.*

In regards to Bioshock 2. The little sister reviving subject Delta is pretty special. She rigged one Vita-chamber to work outside of it's parameters. The chambers were only for Ryan and his DNA. And they were not intended to work years later. But again, we're talking about someone special.

Besides that. No, Ryan's does not show up in Bioshock 2.

> Or ever again for that matter. He **is** dead.

Answer (score 0):

In BioShock 2, once you get to the Fontaine Futuristics area, there is an [audio diary of Andrew Ryan, "Alone at Last"](https://bioshock.fandom.com/wiki/Alone_at_Last), saying that everyone is gone and Fontaine is gone and he's the only one left so this proves he's alive because you kill Fontaine after you kill Andrew Ryan.

> This facility belongs to the city now -- to Ryan Industries… at least until the rioting subsides. While it is unfortunate that such measures had to be taken… I must admit, it is gratifying to see this building condemned. Fontaine is gone. Lamb is gone… or close enough. I am alone at last… alone with my city.

Comment: I've edited in a quote of the audio diary I believe you described. There are only two Andrew Ryan audio diaries in the [Fontaine Futuristics level](https://bioshock.fandom.com/wiki/Fontaine_Futuristics_(Level)), and this is the one that fits your description.

Comment: Unfortunately, this isn't evidence that Ryan survived the events of Bioshock: Frank Fontaine faked his death before the events of Bioshock.

Comment: This is not actually confirming he survived, since its recorded before the events of Bioshock 1. He is talking about getting rid of Fontaine is gone because he thinks he is dead and how Lamb has been imprisoned ("gone... or close enough").

He talks about rioting, which is something that is no longer case in Bioshock 1 or 2, riots have long since disappeared. Only to be left with decaying city.

Comment: Depends what "everyone" and "alone" means. Council members Tenenbaum, Steinman, and Cohen are all still active in Rapture at the start of Bioshock.